# Import interactable Excel document

Tags: excel

Is there a way to import an Excel document to a sharepoint list that is intereactable just as it would be in Excel? I've tried but the functions wouldn't follow with the list to sharepoint, only the text, which is editable but the functions isn't there behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Excel and SharePoint are two different applications.

You can work with Field references in a Calculated Column, but only the ones from its own ListItem (row) and only for the most simple datatypes (Text, Number, single Lookup)

So Excel functionality that does anything outside of this one Row scope does not work.

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions
for a complete list of Functions that do work in SharePoint

### Alternatives:

#### Export a SharePoint list to Excel

Your SharePoint data will be available in an Excel sheet, you can link to the content from other Sheets (or Files) and continue with Excel functionality there

#### Link a SharePoint list to Access

Same concept as Excel... but.. MS-Access is more powerful than Excel because it can also write back data to your SharePoint List